# R equivalent of SAS put statement

Tags: r, dplyr, sas

Is there an equivalent in *R* to the *SAS* `put` statement for the purpose of creating a new variable by matching an existing variable to a list.

Let's say I wanted to use a list of zip codes and census MSAs.

There's a list of all zips and all MSAs:

```
zip       censusmsa
94114     "San Francisco-Oakland, CA"
...
```

(and so on, all zips in the US)

I want to match a zip code from an address file and create the `MSA` field. In *SAS* I'd run:

```
hsmsaarea=(put(hszip_use,$zipmsa.));
```

Which says "create hsmsaarea by taking zip from working file and matching to a list called '$zipmsa' stored in a library". If zip in address file matchines something in the library file, put the MSA value in the working file.

Is there a similar *R* function that's not a join or merge? Something I can run as a stand-alone line or ideally in a *dplyr* chain?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at `match`.

Comment: Is there is a specify reason why you're not looking for a join or merge? You might need to be more specific about how you're storing these data in R (dataframes vs vectors or lists).

Comment: Is that really how the `put` function works in SAS? I don't get that from http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000199354.htm

Comment: 6 hours later only ? come on be more charitable to a *SAS* user trying to see the light :). The question is not bad but it would be nice to clarify by adding the expected output.

Comment: Apologies for any delay in responses, other work things took up space. Coming back to this problem now... 

1) not sure that match exactly gets at what I need, have to play around with it a bit. 

2) Exploring options beyond join or merge b/c in SAS I found the put option to be more efficient than a merge. 

3) the put() function does a number of things, this is just one use that had been helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might want one of the following :

```
df <- read.table(h= T, strin = F, text = 'zip       censusmsa
                 94114     "San Francisco-Oakland, CA"
                 12345     "foo"')

zipmsa <- c(`94114` = "bar", `12345` = "baz", `54321` = "qux")
df$MSA <- zipmsa[as.character(df$zip)]
df
#     zip                 censusmsa MSA
# 1 94114 San Francisco-Oakland, CA bar
# 2 12345                       foo baz

zipmsa <- c(baz = 12345, bar = 94114, qux = 54321)
df$MSA <- names(zipmsa[match(df$zip, zipmsa)])
df
#     zip                 censusmsa MSA
# 1 94114 San Francisco-Oakland, CA bar
# 2 12345                       foo baz
```

If you start from a named `list` rather than a named vector, use `unlist` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Moody_Mudskipper for the answer, here's the full solution...

First, I needed to import a list of all zips and their corresponding MSA;

```
zipmsa_mine <- read.table(file="C:/Data/ziptomsa.txt", header = TRUE, StringsAsFactors = FALSE, colClasses = c('character', 'character'))
head(zipmsa_mine)
    zip                            msa
1 00210 Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH
2 00211 Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH
3 00212 Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH
```

Then I turned the resulting table into a named list:

```
zipmsa_mine_l <- structure(as.character(zipmsa_mine$zip), names = as.character(zipmsa_mine$msa))

 #head(zipmsa_mine_l)
#Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH 
#                       "00210"                        "00211" 
#Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH 
#                       "00212"                        "00213" 
#Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH Boston-Cambridge-Quincy, MA-NH 
#                       "00214"
```

The table I in which I want to create the MSA value:

```
df <- read.table(h= T, strin = F, text = 'zip       college
                 "94132"     "SFSU"
                 "19104"     "UPenn")
```

And, the match:

```
df$MSA4 <- names(zipmsa_mine_l[match(df$zip, zipmsa_mine_l)])
```

Which gets;

```
  #zip college                           MSA
#1 94132    SFSU           San Francisco-Oakland-Fremont, CA
#2 19104  UPenn Philadelphia-Camden-Wilmington, PA-NJ-DE-MD
```

Better than a join or merge? Not sure, guess I could run a test. The datasets I'll be working on could have tens of thousands or even 100K+ records. And in SAS I found the put statement a bit more efficient than a merge.